# OpenXML Add Cell to WorkSheet

Tags: c#, excel, powershell, openxml, worksheet

I am currently doing my head in working over the OpenXML 2.5 Framework on the MSDN site here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc861607.aspx

All methods I have tried to add a cell to an existing worksheet corrupt the workbook as the MSDN site only outlines creating the worksheet and not modifying it.

Everytime I add a cell the system wants a whole new worksheet and will not allow the addition of a cell to an existing worksheet. I have been banging my head for hours going over MSDN and Googling this with no luck.

The problem is I need a class that can receiving strings and update the excel file. Has anyone been able to add a cell to an existing worksheet? My issue seems to be due to a string by string solution.

Working input (PowerShell) only works if a new Worksheet is created for the Cell,

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='Medium')]
$cSharpData = (
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("DocumentFormat.OpenXml"),
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("WindowsBase"),
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Linq")
)
[String]$cSharpClass = Get-Content .\method.cs
$cSharpType = Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $cSharpData -TypeDefinition $cSharpClass

$testData = Get-WmiObject Win32_QuickFixEngineering
[DoExcelMethod]::CreateXLSX('.\test.xlsx')

$locNo = 1
[DoExcelMethod]::AddSheetData('.\test.xlsx', $testData, 'TestWS', 'A', $locNo)
```

The file this is point at has the following,

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

public class DoExcelMethod {

    private static int SharedDataItem(string sData, SharedStringTablePart ssPart) {
        if (ssPart.SharedStringTable == null) {
            ssPart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
        }
        int cnt = 0;
        foreach (SharedStringItem sspItem in ssPart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>()) {
            if (sspItem.InnerText == sData) {
                return cnt;
            }
            cnt++;
        }
        ssPart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(sData)));
        ssPart.SharedStringTable.Save();
        return cnt;
    }

    private static WorksheetPart InsertWorksheet(string wsName, WorkbookPart wbPart) {
        WorksheetPart newWsPart = wbPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        newWsPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
        newWsPart.Worksheet.Save();
        Sheets sheets = wbPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
        string relId = wbPart.GetIdOfPart(newWsPart);
        uint sheetId = 1;
        if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0) {
            sheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
        }
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = wsName };
        sheets.Append(sheet);
        wbPart.Workbook.Save();
        return newWsPart;
    }

    private static Cell InsertCellInWorksheet(string columnName, uint rowIndex, WorksheetPart worksheetPart) {
        Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
        SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
        string cellReference = columnName + rowIndex;
        Row row;
        if (sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).Count() != 0) {
            row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First();
        } else {
            row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };
            sheetData.Append(row);
        }
        if (row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == columnName + rowIndex).Count() > 0) {
            return row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).First();
        } else {
            Cell refCell = null;
            foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>()) {
                if (string.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellReference, true) > 0) {
                    refCell = cell;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference };
            row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);
            worksheet.Save();
            return newCell;
        }
    }

    public static void CreateXLSX(string xlsxFile) {
        SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(xlsxFile, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Default" };
        sheets.Append(sheet);
        workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
        spreadsheetDocument.Close();
    }

    public static void AddSheetData(string xlsxFile, string psData, string wsName, string psCol, uint psRow) {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument sSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(xlsxFile, true)) {
            SharedStringTablePart ssPart;
            if (sSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().Count() > 0) {
                ssPart = sSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
            } else {
                ssPart = sSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
            }
            int ssIns = SharedDataItem(psData, ssPart);
            WorksheetPart wsPart = InsertWorksheet(wsName, sSheet.WorkbookPart);
            Cell cell = InsertCellInWorksheet(psCol, psRow, wsPart);
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(ssIns.ToString());
            cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.SharedString);
            wsPart.Worksheet.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

So despite this working I cannot get a cell into an existing worksheet, can anyone help as I am going insane :(

Thanks all

Comment: OpenXML is great in the sense that it's available, but bad in that it's brutally difficult to work with, almost as if Microsoft doesn't really want us to. The good news is that for Excel you can use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) which provides a much easier syntax to work with. I'd go straight to using it.

Comment: There is also a library called closedXML that I use when I have to create excels in c#, it is really simple to use like creating files,worksheets, and cells https://closedxml.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks Scott, following the link I see this is referring to Office 2007/Office 2010. Do you know if this works with Office 2013 / 2016? I have 2 fully workable solutions, one using PowerShell Export-XLSX but this is Office 2007 and does not work for Office 2013/16, the other been to open Excel and paste data (via code) but then you cant license Excel on a Server. Will be good to know about compatibility if this is known, Thanks

Comment: Thanks Guys, works well but not with Office 2016 so I am back to OpenXML 2.5 just so that files can be opened in Office Excel 2016. I will post here once I crack this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you have is in the call to `InsertWorksheet` in `AddSheetData`. You are calling the `InsertWorksheet` method irrespective of whether or not the worksheet already exists. Instead of doing that, you can first search for the worksheet then if it exists you can use it and if it doesn't you can create a new one.

Firstly, you can search for a `WorksheetPart` by its name using a method such as this one (taken from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165637/having-trouble-reading-excel-file-with-the-openxml-sdk/25169876#25169876)):

```
private static WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPartBySheetName(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetName)
{
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = null;

    //find the sheet (note this is case-sensitive)
    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName);

    if (sheets.Count() > 0)
    {
        string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
        worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
    }

    return worksheetPart;
}
```

If that method finds the `WorksheetPart` then it will return it, if not it will return `null`.

Once you have that you just need a small tweak to `AddSheetData` to call `GetWorksheetPartBySheetName` then only call `InsertWorksheet` if that method returns `null`. To do that you can replace this line

```
WorksheetPart wsPart = InsertWorksheet(wsName, sSheet.WorkbookPart);
```

with this

```
WorksheetPart wsPart = GetWorksheetPartBySheetName(sSheet.WorkbookPart, wsName);
if (wsPart == null)
    wsPart = InsertWorksheet(wsName, sSheet.WorkbookPart);
```