# Apply OpenXML excel number formatcode to string value in C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

Using OpenXML in C#, does anybody knows how to apply an excel number formatcode - for instance *(* #,##0.00*);*(* (#,##0.00);*(* "-"??*);*(@_) - to a string value?

Example, if I have a value "10.52982" I should obtain "10.53"

Thanks

PS I don't want to use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly which provides WorksheetFunction.Text function

Comment: Are you struggling with loading the format from the document or turning the Excel format into a c# format? - Does anything in this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007190/openxml-to-create-a-datatable-from-excel-money-cell-value-incorrect/25183597#25183597

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    //Create Document
    SpreadsheetDocument googleSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(GoogleSpreadhSheetStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    WorkbookPart cWorkbookPart = googleSpreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart(); 

    //Create stylesheet
    WorkbookStylesPart spStyles = cWorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
    spStyles.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
    spStyles.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats = new NumberingFormats();

    uint iExcelIndex = 164;
    //Create format
    NumberingFormat nf2decimal = new NumberingFormat();
    nf2decimal.NumberFormatId = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(3453);//UInt32Value.FromUInt32(iExcelIndex++);
    nf2decimal.FormatCode = StringValue.FromString("0.00");
    spStyles.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Append(nf2decimal);

    //Create cellFormat 
    CellFormat numFormat = new CellFormat();
    numFormat.FormatId = 0;
    numFormat.FillId = 0;
    numFormat.BorderId = 0;
    numFormat.FormatId = 0;
    numFormat.NumberFormatId = nf2decimal.NumberFormatId;
    numFormat.ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true);

    //Apped cellformat for cells                   
    spStyles.Stylesheet.CellFormats.AppendChild<CellFormat>(cellFormat);
    //update styles and format count
    spStyles.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Count = UInt32Value.FromUInt32((uint)spStyles.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.ChildElements.Count);
    spStyles.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Count = UInt32Value.FromUInt32((uint)spStyles.Stylesheet.CellFormats.ChildElements.Count);

    //save the changes to the stylesheet
    spStyles.Stylesheet.Save();
    googleSpreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
```

And when setting the value of the cell, use the format index. Since I just added one, the format index should be 1

```
     SheetData cSheetData = (SheetData)GetWorkSheet(sheetId).Where(x => x.LocalName == "sheetData").First();
     Row currentRow = new Row();
     Cell cell = new Cell();
     currentRow.RowIndex = Convert.ToUInt32(cSheetData.ChildElements.Count()) + 1;
     cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
     cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value.Value);
     cell.StyleIndex = 1;
     cell.CellReference = nextCol + rowIndex;
     currentRow.AppendChild(cell);
     cSheetData.Append(currentRow);


     GetWorkSheet(sheetId).Save(); //this returns the reference to my sheet doc to save it
```

Hope this helps you out